# How to choose the Image Kernel size?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to image processing using opencv(C++) and I'm trying to develop a naive application to teach myself the basics related to it such as the morphology operations, edge detection, contours, etc. The application aims to extract articles from the image of a newspaper by building rectangular boxes around each article.

[image: sample image]

My approach:
I first binarise the given image followed by which I apply dilation to create connected components. I then wish to group these connected components together into paragraphs and headings and then move onto clubbing the individual entities of an article into one. But the problem is that I am unable to decide what the size of the Kernel should be which I use to apply dilation to form these connected components, is there a way to dynamically determine the kernel size in some way?

[image: sample output image]

Code: http://www.mediafire.com/file/801rch2rrcrn8jy/att2.cpp

Comment: What have you tried? with code.

Comment: @Silencer Otsu thresholding to begin with, then dilation to thicken the text using a predefined size (3x3) MORPH-CROSS and then finding the contours in the image, and building rectangles around them.